# How do I sort Year range array in descending order dynamically

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this kind of dynamic array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2011-12
    [1] => 2018-19
    [2] => 2016-17
    [3] => 2010-11
    [4] => 2009-10
    [5] => 2007-08
    [6] => 2012-13
    [7] => 2015-16
    [8] => 2017-18
    [9] => 2008-09
    [10] => 2013-14
    [11] => 2014-15
)
```

How do I sort it in descending order ?

like I want this type of output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2018-19
    [1] => 2017-18
    [2] => 2016-17
    
)
```

and so on ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are just trying to order them by Descending order.
Try: `rsort($yourArray);`
The output will be :

```
Array
{
[13] => 2018-19
[12] => 2017-18
[11] => 2016-17
...
}
```

The indexing will be the same because the `rsort()` function all it does is just sorting your array in reverse mode (which I think that's what you are trying to do).